# A loop to iteratively arrive at rowsums = colsums for i = j

Tags: python, r, logic

I do apologize my question is going to be wordy because i'm just at a loss on how to even start coding this. Pseudo-code answers are highly appreciated if only to allow me to understand how to solve this (then I can write some actual code and come back for help if necessary).

My problem isn't so much the code as it is understanding the logic I need (which is arguably the harder part of programming).

An informal explanation of my problem is that  want to change a matrix A (which happens to be sparse) such that the row sums are equal to the column sums. I can do this by adding to A a matrix AS where S is a matrix of scales.

Formally, I want to find an S matrix such that (A + AS)ONESn = T and (t(A) + T(A)S)ONESn = T where ONESn is a vector of ones that creates T, the vector of row sums.

The vector T is set in stone as it were, it is the current column sums and is the target for the row sums.

I think the way I want to solve this is for each row i and column j where i = j I want to find the row sum and compute how far it is from the target. Then I want to change each element of that row such that the row sum equals the target (or is at least "close enough" where I can set the "close enough").

However, this is subject to the condition that the sum of column j must equal the target as well.

How can I design the logic so that I can start with say column 1 and row 1, figure out the values in row 1 and then figure out the values of column 1 subject to the first entry of column 1 being "fixed" by the earlier procedure.

Following that, row 2 should have its first value "fixed" by the above, and similarly the programme needs to figure out column 2 with fixed values for the first two entries now.

And so on until you get to the final column and row

I have tried programming a gradient descent but got stick on how to make the gradient descent for the columns depend on the gradient descent for the rows iteratively.

I've also worked this out by hand (for a 2x2 matrix), I can figure out the answer but I'm not sure how I managed to do so which is why I'm struggling to code it.

Suppose A is a 2x2 matrix of [1, 2, 3, 4]. Row sums are are [4, 6]. Column sums are [3, 7].

```
1 3  | 4 
2 4  | 6
___
3 7
```

if I add the matrix S = [1, 0, -1, 0]

```
1 -1
0  0
```

I get A + S = [2, 2, 2, 4] which has row sums [4, 6].

```
2 2  | 4 
2 4  | 6
___
4 6
```

Expected results are a matrix (A + AS) such that the row sums equal the column sums.

Or an error message saying "does not converge"

Comment: Might be better to ask on https://math.stackexchange.com - one advantage is it supports math markup so you can express exactly what you want more clearly.

Comment: It'd help if you include your hand-calculated example.

Comment: You are doing (A + S), but asking for (A + AS). I don't understand. Am I missing something?

Comment: matrix A should be a square matrix. @Shree A+AS can be obtained from A+S' if A is an invertible matrix.

Comment: As @Marius suggested its better to ask this in https://math.stackexchange.com or https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can the expected results be a diagonal matrix? That's the easiest way for the row sums to equal the column sums...

Comment: One issue clarified; still have the (A+S) or (A + AS) discrepancy, and the question about the diagonal matrix as a result.

Comment: @kBORTDoes my post answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

You have some matrix A and you need to add another matrix S so that the resulting matrix M has same row sums as column sums. This means:

A + S = M # For M row sums = column sums

So what you need to do is to find S. You can simply change the equotion to

S = M - S

Now you can set any matrix with same row sum and column sum for M and you get S. Once you have S you can do

A + S = M.

This means that you can add to every matrix A another matrix S so that the resulting matrix M has row sums= column sums. Hence, you will not get the messege "matrix does not converge".

Here is a R code

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(4), ncol= 2)
M <- matrix(c(2,2,2,4), ncol= 2)
S <- M - A
rowSums(A+S) == colSums(A+S)
TRUE TRUE
```

Or, more general:

```
row_col_num <- 5 # number of columns and rows
A <- matrix(rnorm(row_col_num *row_col_num ), ncol= row_col_num )
M <- matrix(rep(1, row_col_num *row_col_num ), ncol= row_col_num )
S <- M - A
rowSums(A+S) == colSums(A+S)
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

The resulting matrix A+S is always as you set M. So I am not sure what this is for. If you need to know how to find S, where A+S gives you a matrix M with row sums= column sums, this is how you can do it.

Comment: The colSums and rowSums of the A + S need to equal the colSums (or rowSums, Q isn't consistent) of the original though. But that's an easy fix; `M <- diag(colSums(A))`.

Comment: This is something I was not sure about because in the description of the question the OP asks for A+S but later for (A + AS). So thanks for the comment.